# How do I get the Standard Error of the coefficients on Sklearn.LinearRegression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

How do I get the Standard Error of each of the coefficients used on Sklearn.LinearRegression? To do a Linear Regression sklearn had to compute the `inverse(X.T.dot(X))` can I access that matrix? How?